# microphone audio data in JavaScript recorder is saved by php server side in unrecognized format

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu, html5-audio

Small web recorder consists of 2 files.
recorder.html - the recorder with save recording button. when pressed javascript function saveRecording() posts audio data to save_recording2.php

a wav file is created but its not a real wav file. Too small. Very small. it forced into wav format but not recognized as wav format when I try to access it with mmpeg to convert to a different format, conversion fails.

I am unsure of the correct way to save the audio data in any format that is valid.

The saved file is playable with audio controls as wav.

I also tried different types:

```
            //audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/webm' }); 
      //audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type : 'audio/wav;          codecs=MS_PCM' });
  audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type : 'audio/wav; codecs=0' });
```

recorder.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Recording Program</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="startButton">Start Recording</button>
  <button id="stopButton">Stop Recording</button>
  <button id="saveButton" disabled>Save Recording</button>
  <div id="recordingsList"></div>

  <script>
    let mediaRecorder;
    let chunks = [];
    let audioBlob; // Global variable to store the audio blob

    const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
    const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
    const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
    const recordingsList = document.getElementById('recordingsList');

    startButton.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
    stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveRecording);

    function startRecording() {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(function(stream) {
          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
          });

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', function() {
            audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/webm' }); // Store the audio blob
            const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
            const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.controls = true;
            audioElement.src = audioURL;
            recordingsList.appendChild(audioElement);
            saveButton.disabled = false;
            chunks = [];
          });

          mediaRecorder.start();
          startButton.disabled = true;
          stopButton.disabled = false;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.error('Error accessing microphone: ', err);
        });
    }

    function stopRecording() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      startButton.disabled = false;
      stopButton.disabled = true;
    }

    function saveRecording() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('audio', audioBlob); // Use the stored audio blob

      fetch('save_recording2.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Recording saved successfully!');
          } else {
            console.error('Error saving recording:', response.statusText);
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Error saving recording:', error);
        });
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

save_recording2.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Log the POST data
    $logMessage = 'POST Data: ' . print_r($_POST, true);
    logToFile($logMessage, 'logger.txt');

    if (isset($_FILES['audio']) && $_FILES['audio']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'];
        $originalFileName = $_FILES['audio']['name'];

        // Generate a unique filename
        //$extension = pathinfo($originalFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $extension = "wav";
        $targetFile = 'recordings/' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;

        if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile)) {
            $logMessage = 'Recording saved successfully! Filename: ' . $targetFile;
            logToFile($logMessage, 'logger.txt');

            // Execute the audio_processing_script.py script
            $pythonScript = 'audio_processing_script.py';
            $audioFilePath = $targetFile;
            $command = "python3 $pythonScript $audioFilePath";

            // Execute the command and capture the output
            $output = shell_exec($command);

            // Log the output to the logger.txt file
            logToFile($output, 'logger.txt');

            echo 'Recording saved successfully!';
        } else {
            $logMessage = 'Error saving recording.';
            logToFile($logMessage, 'logger.txt');
            echo $logMessage;
        }
    } else {
        $logMessage = 'No audio file uploaded.';
        logToFile($logMessage, 'logger.txt');
        echo $logMessage;
    }
} else {
    $logMessage = 'Invalid request.';
    logToFile($logMessage, 'logger.txt');
    echo $logMessage;
}

function logToFile($message, $filename) {
    $log = date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]') . ' ' . $message . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($filename, $log, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the python code do? Is the file uploaded correctly before python processes it? We need to narrow down the issue to a smaller area.

Comment: @ADyson loads correctly. Also  apparantly audio from microphone does get saved correctly as audio/webm. I had php save file and then python uses ffmpeg to convert webm to mp3 then return the the audio length. Working now. Should I post the python or delete the question?

Comment: `Working now`...what did you change to make it work? That might be worth posting as an Answer. (If it involves changing the python code, then add the original code to the question, and the changed code to the answer).